# UIViews behind "pass through" UIView isn't VO accessible

Tags: ios, uikit, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a case where a transparent `UIViewController` is presented over a map view.
ViewController.view is transparent and it's a "pass-through" view. This means that all of ViewController's touches are passed to the map view that is behind the VC.

"Pass through" behaviour is implemented by

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    for subview in subviews {
        if !subview.isHidden && subview.alpha > 0 && subview.isUserInteractionEnabled && subview.point(inside: convert(point, to: subview), with: event) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

All touches and gestures work perfectly, but I found that VoiceOver doesn't work at all. MapView isn't VO accessible. I can't select any mapView element with VO.
I did some research and found that VO uses a private method:

```
[UIViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]
```

And looks like this method doesn't use the overridden pointInside method. So does anyone know how to fix it in a safe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make VoiceOver ignore the view by setting `view.isAccessibilityElement = NO;`.

Alternately, you can make `view` conform to `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol. If for some reason that doesn’t work, you can set `view.accessibilityElements = @[mapView, ...];`

Comment: `view.accessibilityElements = @[mapView, ...];` works. The solution is so simple!

In case with GoogleMaps (GMSMapView) you need to pass GMSMapView and every GMSMarker.